# What is done when memory gets filled: One page eviction or an entire process is killed?

Tags: linux, memory, out-of-memory

The question is simple but I haven't found information (to be more precise, I have found information about both options (options below) but without saying which one is used in each situation).

Option 1: The kernel decides which is the best page that can evict from memory and swap to disk and eviction occurs so that the new page can arrive.

Option 2: The kernel kills one (or several) processes to free up considerable memory space at once.

2nd option seems better in performance (instead of going one by one, you free many memory pages at once) but it has the problem that is killing processes. So, which of the two options that I mentioned are implementing the modern linux distributions? Does it depend on the exact situation?

If it depends on the exact linux distribution please answer it in a general way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are used, depending on the circumstances.

When the kernel needs to allocate pages, and there are none available (or the watermarks have been reached), it will try to reclaim pages from the inactive lists (look for “Inactive” in `/proc/meminfo`). Reclaiming a page there doesn’t necessarily involve swap:

- non-dirty, file-backed pages will be discarded (they can be restored from their backing store);
- dirty, file-backed pages will be written to their backing store and discarded;
- only evictable pages with no backing store of their own will involve swap.

The OOM killer only steps in when the above isn’t sufficient; it chooses the “worst” process (based on a number of criteria) and kills it.

Comment: So that means that if we can evict only 1 page following that criteria, only 1 page will be removed and replaced for a new page. But if we can't follow that criteria (for example swap space is full and we only have dirty anonymous pages) one entire process will be killed. Right? So, tell me if the following is correct please: if memory is full but swap area has space -> That criteria is followed, only 1 page eviction. If both main memory and swap area are full but we have non-dirty or file-backed pages -> that criteria is followed, only 1 page eviction. Other case->OOM killer kills a process.

Comment: That’s a good enough approximation to start with. The OOM killer’s criteria are a bit more complex ;-). See [the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/concepts.html) for an overview of the concepts.

Comment: Could you take a look at the answer I have provided? It is an extension of my previous comment to better understand your answer. Obviously I will mark your answer as the valid one but maybe the answer I have provided may help other students like me who still have a lot of things to learn. I would be super grateful if you could confirm the correctness of that answer in a comment, or correct what's wrong. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Pages will be swapped out as long as there's swap space. They're brought  back in via Page Fault interrupts.

If there is no swap space, a section of the kernel is handwaved into existence as a process, the "OOM-killer", which kills other processes to free memory.

Comment: "a section of the kernel is handwaved into existence as a process"?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the perfect answer from @StephenKitt, which is the official accepted answer. But for those who are students like me and still have a lot to learn to understand it 100%, I want to do this simplified approximation of the answer to the question based on the Stephen Kitt's answer:

**if we don't have enough space in main memory, the evicted page will be selected, and this page can be any of this types:**

-A non-dirty file-backed page. If we are in this case, the page can be removed from memory (and not copied to swap area!!).

-A dirty file-backed page. If we are in this case, the page can be removed from memory but not copied to the swap area!! (and its content copied to its file-backed place).

-A non file-backed page (regardless of whether it's dirty or not). If we are in this case, the page must be copied to swap area. But, if there is not enough space in the swap area, the OOM killer has to kill an entire process (or a few of them).

Comment: You’ve rephrased my answer but with your pre-existing interpretation, thereby introducing mistakes. Distinguishing between “space in swap” and “no space in swap” is misleading: it’s only relevant for the last of the first three items in your lists.

Comment: I've edited it consequently to your comment, could you now confirm its correctness? Thanks again for your patience!!!